# Does Warlords of Draenor contain all previous Expansions?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I own the starter edition, have played it to level 20, and now I want the full content. I want the entire game. I plan on going to the store and buying WoD and a time card. Is that all I need, yes or no?

If your answer is no, explain what I need for the **entire game**.

I know of the deals online and the battle chest, but I couldn't care less about it, so you don't even need to talk about it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The starter edition is Free. You do not own anything yet.

What you need:

1. [World of Warcraft ($20)](https://us.battle.net/shop/en/product/world-of-warcraft) - This will come with 1 month of free game time, and currently contains all expansions EXCEPT Warlords of Draenor.
2. [(Optional) Warlords of Draenor ($50)](https://us.battle.net/shop/en/product/world-of-warcraft-warlords-of-draenor) - This includes one level 90 character boost.

If you wish to continue playing after a month, you will need to buy game time either via subscription, game card, or a Game Time Token (purchasable in-game from other players for gold!)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](http://www.dualshockers.com/2014/10/14/all-world-of-warcraft-accounts-updated-to-mists-of-pandaria-with-warlords-of-draenor-pre-launch-patch/), you only need to buy the base game ($20 on their official store) and the latest expansion to have access to all the content.

*"To make the transition to the new Warlords of Draenor expansion as seamless as possible for current and returning players, all previous expansions have been added to all existing World of Warcraft accounts. This means that all current subscribers and anyone that reactivates their dormant subscription will automatically have all the content through Mists of Pandaria available to them."*

Comment: Might want to consider adding an excerpt from the article to your answer (in case that site goes away)

Comment: Added quote from the article.

Comment: Mists of Pandaria is not the full game.

Comment: According to any information I can find (I'm not a WoW player) MoP was the most recent expansion prior to the release of WoD. Is there some content in between, or which is not included in the base game?